# chown from both ends of very long file list

Tags: command-line, permissions, files, nfs

I have a file list on an NFS that contains 2 million+ nodes. I have to run quite a few file permissions changes, owner changes, etc. When I run commands like `chmod` and `chown` (even `rm` or `mv`), the processes take quite a while to complete since they each have to visit every node in the filesystem.

I'd like to achieve some quasi-form of parallelization on this since I have shared access through NFS. Is there a way to break up (shard?) a file list so that running `chown,chmod,rm,mv`, etc on many hosts can complete the total job faster? Imagine 2 hosts starting at both ends and meeting in the middle type of deal.

Answer (score 3):

Meet `parallel` (`sudo apt install parallel`):

> GNU `parallel` is a shell tool for executing jobs in parallel using one
>   or more computers. A job can be a single
>          command or a small script that has to be run for each of the lines in the input. The typical input is a list
>          of files, a list of hosts, a list of users, a list of URLs, or a list of tables. A job can also be a command
>          that reads from a pipe. GNU parallel can then split the input into blocks and pipe a block into each command
>          in parallel.
>   (…)
>   For each line of input GNU `parallel` will execute `command` with the line as arguments. If no command is given,
>          the line of input is executed. **Several lines will be run in parallel.** GNU parallel can often be used as a
>          substitute for `xargs` or `cat | bash`.

#### Example

```
find . -type f -print0 | parallel -0 chmod +w
```

This will recursively find every file in the current directory and run `chmod +w` on it, executing multiple processes – one process per CPU core by default – simultaneously.

For more see [`man parallel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/parallel.1.html), especially the awesome list of explained examples. There's also a [playlist with example videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1) on youtube.

Answer (score 2):

I will be surprised if the limiting factor will not be the server. So I would imagine dessert's solution is reasonable - possibly with the addition of `-j200` and `-X` to run more parallel jobs on the local host and to insert more than 1 argument on each line.

But assume you have lazy clients then this might be a way to do it:

```bsh
doit() {
  chmod +w "$1"
  # do other stuff
}
export -f doit
cat 2millionfilelist.txt |
  parallel --env doit -S nfsclient1,nfsclient2,nfsclient3 doit
```

This defines a function (adapt to your own need). This function is then copied to each of the 3 nfsclients and run with a single argument from 2millionfilelist.txt. This is done in parallel, and the default is to run 1 job per cpucore on each of the 3 clients.

Now GNU Parallel will connect to the nfsclients using `ssh` for each of the files. So the above is probably highly inefficient. But we can do better than that.

```bsh
doitwrap() {
  doit() {
    chmod +w "$1"
    # do other stuff
  }
  export -f doit
  parallel doit
}
export -f doitwrap
cat 2millionfilelist.txt | parallel --env doitwrap -S nfsclient1,nfsclient2,nfsclient3 --pipe -N1000 doitwrap
```

`doit` does the same as before, but now we have a wrapper, that reads from standard input and runs `doit` on the local machine. So now we just need to distribute the `2millionfilelist.txt` evenly to the three clients.

GNU Parallel can do that, too. We transfer doitwrap to each of the three workers and then run it there. Then we pass `2millionfilelist.txt` in blocks of 1000 lines to the 3 workers.

Comment: Super cool! I didn't know this was at all possible. I really like the double wrapper functions. Going to test now and report back in a bit.